# How to update and insert new element in array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I want to store User data in an array. The data is single unique document.lets say the document is like this.

```
User { id: number, name: string }
```

```
{
  _id : 001,
  room: User[],
}
```

I want to do something this...

- push element (User) if `room[]` doesn't have it.
- update User data.

Like there is `upsert` option in update operation.

```
  DB.Collection.updateOne(
      { _id: "001" },
      { $set: { name: "Bar" } },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

How can I do something like this,In an Array of a Document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$set` operation to update Embedded Document with `$(update)` or `$[$[<identifier>]`.But It's not work good with `upsert` So in order insert new Document use `$push`.Do something to update data or append data separately.

```
// push element (User) if room[] doesn't have it.

DB.Collection.updateOne(
    { "room.id": { $ne: "001" } },
    { $push: { "room": { id: "001", name: "Bar" } } },
);

// update User data

DB.Collection.updateOne(
    { "room.id": "001"  },
    { $set { "room.$": { id: "001", name: "Foo" } } },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can use update with $set or $push based on whether you want to update one element in array with override/update or push another element.
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "raj" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "raj" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "raj" ] }
> db.rooms.updateMany(   {},   {$set:{"room":["john"]}} );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 3 }
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "john" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "john" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "john" ] }
> db.rooms.updateMany(   {},   {$push:{"room":["mike"]}} );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 3 }
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ] ] }
> db.rooms.updateMany(   {},   {$push:{"room":"mike"}} );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 3 }
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
>
```

the push will add a field in the document if it does not exist, so a specific check for field room is not required.

```
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "john", [ "mike" ], "mike" ] }
> db.rooms.updateMany(
...   {},
...   {$unset:{"user":""}}
... );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
> db.rooms.updateMany(   {},   {$unset:{"room":""}} );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 3 }
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3 }
> db.rooms.updateMany(   {},   {$push:{"room":"mike"}} );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 3, "modifiedCount" : 3 }
> db.rooms.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "room" : [ "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff51"), "id" : 2, "room" : [ "mike" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e10f2598d922a1e6eff52"), "id" : 3, "room" : [ "mike" ] }
>
```